# VPN on WIN 7...ipad connects but no DNS services

Tags: windows-7, vpn, ipad, pptp

I have set up a vpn on a win 7 machine PPTP and can successfully connect to it from another win 7 machine over the internet and get out with the new ip address. However, when I connect with an ipad, DNS does not work. I have internet access and can get to sites via direct IP address but NOT via name and the new ip address is the target win 7 ip address.

Help?

Thanks

Comment: Is your VPN server (your Windows 7 machine) pushing DNS settings to your iPhone? It seems when the phone is connected to your VPN it has no idea where to go to resolve domain names.

Comment: Clearly it is not....Don't know where to set that up on the Win 7 Server for the incoming connection...